# is it possible to save javascript variables in excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, save, export

like the title said, is it possible to save javascript variables in excel?

Explanation:
I made a form with 5 questions with each 2 possible answers(radio buttons)
i want to save the values of each question in a excel sheet

each time the form is submitted i want it to make a new row with the values of the answers.

Like this:

```
           Answer1    Answer2    Answer3    Answer4    Answer5

Person1
Person2
Person3
Person4
Person5
```

For the people who dont get it
Person 1,2,3,4,5 are rows and Answer 1,2,3,4,5 are collumns in Excel xD

I found a lot of similar questions but nothing exactly like mine and i cant figure it out alone.

Please help me!

Comment: Are you looking to create/save the excel file on the web server or on your user's local machine? In either case client-side javascript alone will not be sufficient - you will need some server-side code to create the file (I'm assuming a delimited file will work as well, I don't think you really need to create an xls or xlsx file).

Comment: On the web server and what if the excel sheet already exist?
than it only have to add a new row with the values

Comment: Filling one Excel file from a web site which is presented possible many users is not a good idea. You can imagine what happens, if multiple users are trying to put something into the file at the same time? I recommend to use a database to store the values. Databases are especially created for such use cases. Then create a special Excel file for each user which is requesting such a file. Of course even for this you need server side programming. This is not possible with client side Javascript alone. You should mention which server side programming language you can use.